# Why do people avoid going outside during eclipse time?

Tags: belief, eclipse

Generally people avoid going outside during eclipse time. Pujari closes the temple's door  during eclipse time.

What is the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ancient time itself, our ancestors follow the practice of staying inside, eating nothing etc. Some says its just a pure myth and there is nothing scientific in it. But what I know is:

In an eclipse, it is possible to look directly at the sun without much discomfort to your eyes at the time. But doing so can cause severe damage to your eyes without you even knowing it. Also sun rays contain harmful rays like X-Rays,UV Rays etc. This will cause harm to our body.
Also regarding to food, I had read somewhere that,Sun light is the source of all food but during a solar eclipse we only get partial sun light which has passed through moon's atmosphere this light might contain elements/rays that are not completely absorbed by earth's atmosphere and hence there are more chances of contamination of food items during eclipse.

And the reason for closing Temple doors may be

*It is believed that during the solar eclipse, there's a strong negative charge loading on the earth. Since the temples are built to attract astral energy & positively charge the devotees; the positive effects will be reversed during the solar eclipse. Usually, the temples are immediatelly re-opened after the eclipse.*

For more explanations,

- [Eclipse](http://www.swaminarayan.org/faq/eclips.htm)
- [Is solar eclipse a matter of science or faith?](http://toostep.com/debate/is-solar-eclipse-a-matter-of-science-or-faith)

Comment: ok, and what is the reason for closing the temple door during eclipse ?

Comment: This may be the reason:   
*it is believed that during the solar eclipse, there's a strong negative charge loading on the earth. Since the temples are built to attract astral energy & positively charge the devotees; the positive effects will be reversed during the solar eclipse. Usually, the temples are immediatelly re-opened after the eclipse.*

Comment: You should post this comment in the answer.

Comment: Do all you want with your temples, but there isn't the slightest scientific reason to avoid going out in an eclipse. Sunlight during an eclipse does not (CAN NOT) contain anything more than what exists during full sun.